# How to make this type of fade out with a scrolling text?

Tags: animation, transparency, video, text-object

I'm making a Star Wars Crawl animation and I need to fade out some text but in a very specific way. The Star Wars movies do this type of "fade out":

[image]

Here's where I want to fade out:

[image]

This is a text moving from point A to point B. Sorry if I'm not too clear, I'm new to Blender. Thank you.

[Some extra reference](https://youtu.be/3eVDpFmc5DI?t=83)

Comment: Easy way is to just add a transparent to black gradient, so just add that in post, either with a blend texture made in blender or in some other program. Tell me if you need more clarification.

Comment: @NascentSpace Sounds good, how I can do it in Blender? Thank you.

Comment: Use the compositor to add a blend texture over your footage, or use the built-in editor. Just use a mix rgb node with overlay and plug in the blend texture on top of your footage.